# background-image appearing in the body margin

Tags: html, css

I have always thought that the `background-image` of an element appears in the element itself, its `padding` and `border` but **not** its `margin`. However, while trying to get something else to work I discovered this seems to not be the case and the `background-image` is appearing in the `margin`.

```css
body {
    background: url("https://www.google.co.uk/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png");
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color:red;
    margin: 50px;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rz52z14r/

As can be seen, the background is appearing in the `margin`. Additionally, if I add in `overflow: hidden` the overflow is not actually hidden. Again, I was under the impression the `overflow` is anything outside the bounds of the element, i.e., element and padding **not** including the `margin`.

So, overall: why is the background image appearing in the `margin`? And why is the overflow not hidden?

**EDIT:** *there have been a few similar answers to the question; all of which provide a solution to the situation. However, the situation is fictional. What I would like to know is **why does this behaviour occur on the*** `<body>` ***tag but not any other tag?***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why this occurs is because the root element is treated as a special case when rendering the `background`. In effect, the `background` is not being applied to the `body` but to the canvas:

> The background of the root element becomes the background of the canvas and covers the entire canvas, anchored (for 'background-position') at the same point as it would be if it was painted only for the root element itself. The root element does not paint this background again.

*The background (http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html#background)*

But the root element in this case would be the `html` element wouldn't it? Well, the following states that it is preferred to apply the `background` to the `body` rather than the `html` element:

> For HTML documents, however, we recommend that authors specify the background for the BODY element rather than the HTML element.

*The background (http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html#background)*

If the `background-color` and `background-image` of the `html` element is `transparent` and `none` respectively the rules regarding the canvas apply to the `body` element instead:

> For documents whose root element is an HTML "HTML" element or an XHTML "html" element that has computed values of 'transparent' for 'background-color' and 'none' for 'background-image', user agents must instead use the computed value of the background properties from that element's first HTML "BODY" element or XHTML "body" element child when painting backgrounds for the canvas, and must not paint a background for that child element. Such backgrounds must also be anchored at the same point as they would be if they were painted only for the root element.

*The background (http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html#background)*

So, to make a `background` on the `body` respect the `margin`s simply add a `background-color` to the `html` element in CSS:

```css
html {
    background-color: red;
}
body {
    background: url("https://www.google.co.uk/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png");
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color:red;
    margin: 50px;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Apply `background-image` to your container, not to your body.

```
p {
    background: url("https://www.google.co.uk/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png");
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color:red;
    margin: 50px;
}
```

See : https://jsfiddle.net/rz52z14r/9/

Comment: Yes this works, as shown in the answer below: but why?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you are trying to do but the background image you have is sitting in the `.body` tag. And not the `.Body p`

https://jsfiddle.net/rz52z14r/12/

Comment: Yes that is correct. I am not trying to do anything per se. I just saw it when I was editing something in a "Try It" editor. I have never read any rule which states that the background-image of a <body> element does not abide by the same rules as other elements, e.g., <p>. My question is **why** does this occur?

Comment: I see where you're coming from now. The body has a margin applied to it but still the image is acting like there is no margin?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. If you check the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rz52z14r/) you can see the image is way overshooting the border of the <body> (red line) and expanding into the margin.

Comment: If you use .background-positon: top 50px left 50px it could act like it was in the margin. see https://jsfiddle.net/rz52z14r/14/

Comment: That would work; however, I am not after a solution - rather I am after an explanation of the reasoning/theory behind why the behavior is how it is.